# Translating Bro_Log Timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timestamp from a JSON output of some brologs, that looks like this:

```
2016-11-22T19:22:56.178Z
```

How can I translate that into a more easily readable format using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is  the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format , you can use  [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to convert the string into Date Object

```
 Date.parse("2016-11-22T19:22:56.178Z")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!